# How to split in javascript without getting a comma before the word

Tags: javascript, split

I would like to split a variable without getting a `,`.

for example:

```js
var i = document.getElementById('input').value
i.split("search: ")
document.getElementById(`title`).innerHTML = `${i}`
```

if the user had written: search: hi
the output will be:

```
title:    ,hi
```

I would like to find a way to get rid of the `,`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Your code doesn't do what you've described. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Something like `i.split("search: ").replace(",", "")`?